# How to stop cassandra creating jumbo frames?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax

cassandra is generating jumbo frames and our MTU was set to default i.e 1500. So, the packets are getting blocked by the network devices and the send Q is increasing. Is there a way to stop cassandra creating these jumbo frames??

```
tcp    0      0     x.x.x.1:7000     x.x.x.2:55190    ESTABLISHED     xxxxx/java
tcp    0     38872    x.x.x.1:57364    x.x.x.2:7000     ESTABLISHED     xxxxx/java
tcp    0      0     x.x.x.1:57397    x.x.x.2:7000     ESTABLISHED     xxxxx/java
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be totally wrong, but I always thought that the frame size is configured on the networking layer's level, not on the application. Application only sends the data and then the network layer is determining how to deliver it to the client or peer. You should check the OS Settings. Here is one of the links to that: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-redhat-fedora-debian-linux-mtu-size/

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this without increasing the MTU??